# Check if dynamic object has the base of Foo

Tags: c#, reflection

We have these two classes

```
class Foo{
    public Foo(){}
}

class FooBar : Foo{
    public FooBar : base() {}
}
```

I know that you can see if the type of a dynamic object is something like

```
dynamic bar = new FooBar();
bool isType = bar is FooBar;
```

But how can I check if bar is of type foo?

As in

```
dynamic bar = new FooBar();
//This would need to check the base as well
bool isType = bar is Foo;
```

Or would that already work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that will already work. `is` simply checks to see if the object can be casted to the given type. See the documentaiton on it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Sweet. I thought it literally meant FooBar is FooBar not FooBar is compatible with Foo

Comment: For that you would want `bar.GetType() == typeof(Foo)`.

Comment: But bar in Foo already works? I would rather use a "native" function then accessing members.

Comment: If you want to be more specific, I do not believe there is an alternative to `GetType()`. But if you only require that the object in question implements that type (which is better practice, as it makes your code work with derived types) go with `is`.

Comment: I am using a dynamic object and then checking if that object has that type so I know that I can set those properties.

Comment: Then `is` is fine. `bar.GetType() == typeof(Foo)` will be false if bar is of type `FooBar`, as it is in your previous example. It will only hold if bar is directly of type `Foo`, and will be false otherwise.